# How to avoid caching null values in redis cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, jsr107

```
@CacheResult(cacheName = "testCache)
public Employee geteEmployee(@CacheKey String empId) {
   //logic
   return employee;
}
```

If employee is null, that null value should not be cached.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [cacheNull](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0-PFD/javax/cache/annotation/CacheResult.html#cacheNull()) property to `false`.

> **cacheNull**
>
> *public abstract boolean cacheNull*
>
> If set to false null return values will not be cached. If true (the default) null return values will be cached.
>
> Defaults to true.
>
> **Default:**
> true

`@CacheResult(cacheName = "testCache", cacheNull = false)`

Comment: cacheNull is not there in cacheResult interface.
I am using below dependency version.
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
   <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: "cacheNull" property is not there in latest "1.1.1" version. It is present in "1.0.0-PFD" version.

Comment: If you use spring anyway, shouldn't you go with its own annotation? `@Cacheable(value="defaultCache", key="#pk", unless="#result == null")`

Comment: We are using jsr-107 cache annotations in our application. @Cacheable annotation is present in org.springframework.cache. Any work around for CacheResult 1.1.1 version for not to cache null values?

Comment: Not unless you are ready to use exceptions like `NoSuchElementException` instead of null. I'd hope future versions would include the attribute from PFD.